# Spring Repository nullpointerexception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to write a really basic application using Spring-Boot. The only thing I'm currently trying is to get some information out of a SQL Server database.

**Application.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackageClasses = { MainView.class, Application.class })
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = CustomerRepository.class)
@EntityScan(basePackageClasses = Customer.class)
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }
}
```

**Customerrepository.java**

```
@Repository
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, Integer> 
{

}
```

**CustomerController.java**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(path = "/customer")
public class CustomerController {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerRepository customerRepository;

    @GetMapping(path = "/all")
    public @ResponseBody Iterable<Customer> getAllCustomers() {
        return customerRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

**CustomersView.java**

```
@Tag("customers-view")
@HtmlImport("src/views/customers/customers-view.html")
@Route(value = ApplicationConst.PAGE_CUSTOMERS, layout = MainView.class)
@PageTitle(ApplicationConst.TITLE_CUSTOMERS)
public class CustomersView extends PolymerTemplate<TemplateModel> {

    @Autowired
    CustomerRepository customerRepository;

    public CustomersView() {
        customerRepository.findAll();
    }

}
```

Going to http://localhost:8080/customer returns every customer in my database just fine.

But when I try to find all the customers in my CustomersView.java, the autowired CustomerRepository returns a nullpointerexception.

Is somebody able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: Error on which line? Have you read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)?

Comment: Or, more likely relevant, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896870/why-is-my-spring-autowired-field-null)?

Comment: error is caused on this line: customerRepository.findAll();

Comment: Does it return null because no data is found or do you get a NullPointerException due to the @autowired Attribute being null?

Comment: try to check it with the link "localhost:8080/costumer/all"

Comment: Please print the stack trace of your error so that we can understand the reason behind the null pointer exception.

Comment: You can use `@PostConstruct` annotation too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to @Autowire the Repository in the constructor like this:

```
@Tag("customers-view")
@HtmlImport("src/views/customers/customers-view.html")
@Route(value = ApplicationConst.PAGE_CUSTOMERS, layout = MainView.class)
@PageTitle(ApplicationConst.TITLE_CUSTOMERS)
public class CustomersView extends PolymerTemplate<TemplateModel> {

CustomerRepository customerRepository;

@Autowired
public CustomersView(CustomerRepository customerRepository) {
    this.costumerRepository = customerRepository;
    this.customerRepository.findAll();
}

}
```

This happens because all @autowired-attributes are inserted after the constructor gets completed. If you want to inject the @autowired-attributes at constructor-time, you have to use the method above.